# C++ name mangling by hand

Tags: python, c++, name-mangling, ida

I am writing a script for the [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) disassembler in Python using the [`idapython`](http://code.google.com/p/idapython/) plugin. Using this, I am able to fill in the gaps where IDA's auto-analysis falls short.

One area that has me stumped is naming locations/functions with (for want of a better term) "pretty names". An example of what I mean is illustrated below:

[image: IDA pretty names sample screenshot]

`idapython` and IDA Pro itself only allow me to enter basic C-ish function names. If I enter disallowed symbols (e.g. the scope resolution operator), they're replaced with underscores. *However*, if I enter a mangled name by hand (e.g. `__ZN9IOService15powerChangeDoneEm`), IDA Pro *will* prettify this for me.

Hence my question: how can I generate mangled names to pass through `idapython`? Is there a name-mangling library available? Is one available in Python? Is my only hope to tear the mangling functionality out of `g++` and work around that?

Comment: I would hope there is some doc around that you could look into... good luck!

Comment: Did you ever get around to implementing C++ name mangling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally got around to dig a little.

Unfortunately I could not find tool, I did find resources though.

If all you want is mangle names in the gcc3 fashion, then know that gcc3 use the Itanium C++ ABI, which has a standardized name mangling scheme. I found two documents:

- The [Itanium C++ ABI](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/cxxabi-1.83.html) page
- A [Calling Convention](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf) PDF document, which describe the schemes of various compilers

For reference, both come from the Wikipedia page on [Name Mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Thanks, I've replaced it with a link to another website (linux-foundation.org).

Comment: I came upon your question b/c of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335624/what-is-linux-utility-to-mangle-a-c-symbol-name?lq=1 which is similar

Answer (score 3):

One simple (alebit hacky) method would be to compile a C++ file with the symbol you want in it, then extract the necessary symbols from the .o file's symbol table. With a bit of work this might be nicely scriptable.

Comment: I did this on my first C++ program, while at high school. Didn't knew that it wasn't santard or anything else. That helped me implement a module system, allowing the soft (game) to be extended easily. I wasn't even aware that this kind of thing were not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [article](http://www.kegel.com/mangle.html) that explains how mangling is done by Visual compiler. For mangling done by gcc, I think you can find the information in the source of the `binutils` package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Clang AST library, which has a MangleContext class.

http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CodeGen_1_1MangleContext.html

Comment: The link is dead...